# After creating JAR using "maven-jar-plugin" along with "*.Properties"(files), methods from JAR are failing as "*.properties" path is changed

Tags: maven, jar

create JAR from maven project, along with all dependable properties files to reuse methods/class from another maven project.

1. properties files are located into src/main/resource under folder-> ConfigFolder
2. When JAR is created the path of ConfigFolder changed and below line of code is failing System.getProperty("user.dir")+/src/test/resource/ConfigFolder/Configfilename.Properties

In maven project - *.Properties is being read by below line of code

new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+/src/test/resource/ConfigFolder/Configfilename.Properties")

When Project is converted into Jar using maven-jar-plugin, the hierarchy of Configfilename.Properties changes hence all my methods are failing.

Before converting JAR Folder Hierarchy
ProjectName(maven project)
|-src/main/java
|-src/test/java
|-src/test/resource
|-ConfigFolder
|-Configfilename.Properties
|-testSuites
|-testng.xml

After converting the into JAR
JARNAME-test.jar
|-ConfigFolder
|-Configfilename.Properties
|-testSuties
|-testng.xml

As you see after converting the jar the hierarchy got changed and new **FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+/src/test/resource/ConfigFolder/Config.Properties") **returns null

requirement is to convert first maven project into JAR and use it into second maven project as first maven project contains n number of reusable methods/class project.

Comment: Inside a jar file the location in the root of the jar as default. You are referencing the source locations instead.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you. is there any way to change my code, not to refer the source path but to the path where Property files are located inside the jar ? I am new to building the jar and looking for a way to rectify the issue.

Comment: The way is to use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/property.file")` also recheck because it looks like your code is using things for testing and for production...a

Comment: @khmarbaise above code worked. Thanks again